# Get multiple users in android 4.2

Tags: android

Is there a way to find the list of users configured in a device(android 4.2+)?

Thanks,
Jeyanthi

Comment: What do you meant that?

Comment: Multiple user is a new feature comes with android 4.2. So we can have more than one user account as we do have in windows OS..So I just wanted to get list of users configured in a device.. http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. If you see `UserManager.java` source code , you can found these methods.
Hovewer, `android.permission.MANAGE_USERS` is needed for these methods.

The `MANAGE_USERS` has a protection level of signature|system, which means that the application has to be signed with the platform key.

```
/**
     * Returns information for all users on this device.
     * Requires {@link android.Manifest.permission#MANAGE_USERS} permission.
     * @return the list of users that were created.
     * @hide
     */
    public List<UserInfo> getUsers() {
        try {
            return mService.getUsers(false);
        } catch (RemoteException re) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Could not get user list", re);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns information for all users on this device.
     * Requires {@link android.Manifest.permission#MANAGE_USERS} permission.
     * @param excludeDying specify if the list should exclude users being removed.
     * @return the list of users that were created.
     * @hide
     */
    public List<UserInfo> getUsers(boolean excludeDying) {
        try {
            return mService.getUsers(excludeDying);
        } catch (RemoteException re) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Could not get user list", re);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Gabriele...I got it...